# Как повторяющийся текст в *.properties заменить переменными

Tags: spring-boot, properties

Есть много повторяющегося текста в **ValidationMessages.properties**

```
validate.PACKAGEID.size = "The field 'PACKAGEID' can contain only {max} symbols.";
validate.msgcode.size = "The field 'MSGCODE' can contain only {max} symbols.";
```

Можно ли сделать что то вроде

```
var1 = "The field"

var2 = "can contain only {max} symbols."

validate.mess =  ${var1} +  'PACKAGEID' + ${var2};
```